# How to read from XML-RPC response

Tags: javascript, xml-rpc

When I do `console.log(response);`:

```
> [{..}]
//expanded
0:
    testmessage:
        testrep:
            12-12-09: {value1: 200, value2: 150, value3: 165}
            12-23-12: {value1: 20, value2: 150, value3: 165}
            01-04-16: {value1: 0, value2: 150, value3: 165}
            12-16-09: {value1: 150, value2: 150, value3: 165}
```

When I do `console.log(response[0].testmessage.testrep);`:

```
> {2017-11-20: {…}, 2017-11-21: {…}, 2017-11-22: {…}, 2017-11-23: {…}}
//expanded
    12-12-09: {value1: 200, value2: 150, value3: 165}
    12-23-12: {value1: 20, value2: 150, value3: 165}
    01-04-16: {value1: 0, value2: 150, value3: 165}
    12-16-09: {value1: 150, value2: 150, value3: 165}
```

I am trying to loop through each date row in `testrep` and get value# values.

I tried to get the length by using `var len = response[0].testmessage.testrep.length` so I can loop through and get the field but it is returning `null`.

How can I achieve the looping and getting the values per date.

Comment: `{...}` are objects.  They don't have a length.  `[...]` are arrays, and do have a length.  Look at your response.  Anything that is in an array you can loop/iterate over.

Comment: Just noticed it. thank you.

Comment: So I am thinking each date is an object or `testrep` so how can I loop through each object and get the property and value?

Comment: Having testrep structured as an object with key being a non-y2k-friendly date and value being an object is of questionable value unless your client app already knows about those dates and can pick them out directly.  More valuable might be to add another property `date` eg, to each of the internal objects with the date value, and contain the list within a normal array.

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(variable)` to get an array of keys for the object, where 'variable' is your object.

Answer (score 1):

`response[0].testmessage.testrep` is an object. As Objects in JS do not have the length property, you can get the length by doing `Object.keys(response[0].testmessage.testrep).length`.

But since you want to loop through. There are several ways to iterate an object in JS. One simple way is:

```
for(var date in response[0].testmessage.testrep) { //javascript 'var'
  var data = response[0].testmessage.testrep[date];
  // do somethings here with data and date
}
```

Comment: Thank you... Fixed it for me. I learnt something new `Objects.keys()`.

Comment: How can I get each value from `data`? I tried `data.valueOf("value1")` and it didn't work.

Comment: `data` is an object. So you can access using either `data.value1` or `data['value1']`. Also `let` and `const` would have worked in most modern browsers.

Comment: It (let and const) gave me an error in VS. I was able to figure it out but thank you. `data.value1` doesn't show for me...